# Arithmetic overflow error after change query order

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer-arithmetic

We have a query like below

```
SELECT p.propertyNumber as propertyNumber,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM #TEM
         WHERE pNumber = p.propertyNumber
           AND dsenderType = 0
           AND dType = 1
           AND reTime >= '2017-03-01 00:00'
           AND reTime <= '2017-04-01 00:00' ) AS temailCount,  
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM #TEM
         WHERE pNumber = p.propertyNumber
           AND dsenderType = 1
           AND dType = 1
           AND dSendStatus = 1
           AND sentTime >= '2017-03-01 00:00'
           AND sentTime <= '2017-04-01 00:00' ) AS temailJobCount,  
       ( SELECT SUM( DATEDIFF( second, reTime, jEnddate ) )
         FROM #TEM
         WHERE pNumber = p.propertyNumber
           AND dsenderType = 0
           AND dType = 1
           AND ( jStatus = 2 OR jStatus = 4 )
           AND jEnddate >= '2017-03-01 00:00'
           AND jEnddate <= '2017-04-01 00:00' ) AS temailturnAroundTime
FROM property p
WHERE p.locationId = 6
GROUP BY propertyNumber
```

---

It throws "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int" error. But it works if we change `SUM( DATEDIFF( second, reTime, jEnddate ) )` to `SUM( DATEDIFF( minute, reTime, jEnddate ) )` and the largest number is 1153447 minutes, which is no more than 70000000 seconds.

The weirdest thing is it works if we change the query order by placing `SUM` function as the second field like (also work if `SUM` is the only field)

```
SELECT p.propertyNumber AS propertyNumber,
       ( SELECT SUM( DATEDIFF( second, reTime, jEnddate ) )
         FROM #TEM
         WHERE pNumber = p.propertyNumber
           AND dsenderType = 0
           AND dType = 1
           AND ( jStatus = 2 OR jStatus = 4 )
           AND jEnddate >= '2017-03-01 00:00'
           AND jEnddate <= '2017-04-01 00:00' ) AS temailturnAroundTime, 
       ( SELECT ......) AS temailCount,
       ( SELECT ......) AS temailJobCount
FROM property p
WHERE p.locationId = 6
GROUP BY propertyNumber
```

We can solve the problem by casting the `DATEDIFF` result as `bigint` but still I cannot figure out why the error occurs. Can anyone give me a clue? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As the server reads row after row to calculate the `SUM` it adds the `int` values together in the internal `int` variable. If during the summation the intermediary result exceeds the `int` capacity (2,147,483,647), the server will stop calculations and throw the error that you see.

The server will stop the query execution even if subsequent values are negative and overall sum would be less than 2,147,483,647.

Apparently, in the first version of your query the server scans through the rows in some order which results in the accumulated intermediary result that exceeds 2,147,483,647. Other versions of the query may be using different index to scan the rows, hence, different order of values summation, which never exceeds 2,147,483,647.

---

It is easy to reproduce.

I'll make a table with a clustered index, add few rows in a different order and calculate `SUM`.
In this simple query the server will scan the table using the clustered index, in the order of this index.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_T] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))
```

### Test 1

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[T];

INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (1, 2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (2, -2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (3, 2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (4, -2147483647);

SELECT SUM([Value]) AS s
FROM [dbo].[T];
```

**Result**

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

+---+
| s |
+---+
| 0 |
+---+
```

### Test 2

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[T];

INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (1, 2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (2, 2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (3, -2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (4, -2147483647);

SELECT SUM([Value]) AS s
FROM [dbo].[T];
```

**Result**

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

---

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to cast the value to `bigint`, as you have found out yourself:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[T];

INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (1, 2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (2, 2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (3, -2147483647);
INSERT [dbo].[T] ([ID], [Value]) VALUES (4, -2147483647);

SELECT SUM(CAST([Value] AS bigint)) AS s
FROM [dbo].[T];
```

This query returns 0 without arithmetic overflow errors.

---

There can be other cases when this error occurs.

The server may calculate the value of the `DATEDIFF(second,reTime,jEnddate)` expression first, then filter out this row according to the `WHERE` clause.

So, if there is a row in the table with the large difference, even if it is filtered out later, it may affect the calculations.

The engine doesn't have to filter out rows first and only then calculate the expression.
You can see what is going on by examining the actual execution plan.

Most likely, when you change the query, the plan changes in such a way that the row(s) with the large difference are filtered out before the expression is calculated.

Do this easy check:

```
select 
    MAX(DATEDIFF(minute,reTime,jEnddate)) AS MaxDiff,
    MIN(DATEDIFF(minute,reTime,jEnddate)) AS MinDiff
from #TEM
```

Note, that there is no `WHERE` in this query. You want to see the global `MAX` and `MIN` difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked and the MaxDiff is 6582081， MinDiff is -75762, also get results when using second unit 394924854/-4545735. Could it be the reason?

Comment: @SLiu, I think the reason is that in some versions of your query the intermediary `SUM` exceeds the capacity of the `int` type. I've added the example to the answer.

Comment: Ooh, that could be the reason. Your example explains everything. I change the query to group by id column with clustered index, no error. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @SLiu, the engine is free to choose any order for scanning the rows. You should not rely on it. My example was for demonstration of the overflow error. In a complex query and large table the order of table scan is not predictable and not stable. Your changed query may run today and fail tomorrow. You should cast your `int` values to `bigint` to guarantee that the overflow will not happen.

Comment: Understood. We already take the bigint cast solution. just want to make more tests to understand the cause.